# Passing and using parameters between JSF includes

Tags: jsf-2, el

I've been trying to understand JSF templating and `include` attributes and passing parameters between components. In *Mastering JavaServer Faces 2.2* by Anghel Leonard, I came across the following example of passing parameters, which I don't fully understand.

Given this bean:

```
@Named
@ViewScoped
public class TemplatesBean implements Serializable {

    private String msgTopDefault="";
    private String msgBottomDefault="";
    private String msgCenterDefault="No center content ... press the below button!";

    public void centerAction(){
        this.msgCenterDefault="This is default content";
    }

    // Getters and setters
}
```

Parameters are passed to `contentDefault.xhtml` with:

```
<ui:insert name="content">
  <ui:include src="/template/default/contentDefault.xhtml">
    <ui:param name="templatesBeanName" value="#{templatesBean}"/>
    <ui:param name="contentPropertyName" value="msgCenterDefault"/>
  </ui:include>
</ui:insert>
```

Then, within `contentDefault.xhtml` the parameters are used as follows:

```
<ui:composition>            
     <h:outputText value="#{templatesBeanName[contentPropertyName]}"/>
     <h:form>
         <h:commandButton value="Center Button" action="#{templatesBeanName['centerAction']()}"/>               
     </h:form>
</ui:composition>
```

I've never used the square-bracket syntax before, but if a reference to `templatesBean` is being passed in, why not just use that to access the properties or invoke action methods? For example, the following code works for me too and seems simpler:

```
<h:form>
     <h:commandButton value="Center Button" action="#{templatesBeanName.centerAction()}"/>
</h:form>
```

Recognising that the example in the book may be a contrived example to illustrate a point, are there use cases where the other syntax is appropriate?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I do not know or own the book, so I cannot investigate that way what they want to illustrate, but I can sort of deduce that by looking at the **full** example you posted, not just the part about the `centerAction`.

If you look at

```
<ui:insert name="content">
  <ui:include src="/template/default/contentDefault.xhtml">
    <ui:param name="templatesBeanName" value="#{templatesBean}"/>
    <ui:param name="contentPropertyName" value="msgCenterDefault"/>
  </ui:include>
</ui:insert>
```

you'll see that ***2*** params are passesd on, *`templatesBeanName`* and *`contentPropertyName`*

In

```
<ui:composition>            
     <h:outputText value="#{templatesBeanName[contentPropertyName]}"/>
     <h:form>
         <h:commandButton value="Center Button" action="#{templatesBeanName['centerAction']()}"/>               
     </h:form>
</ui:composition>
```

from which you just pointed to the line with `action="#{templatesBeanName['centerAction']()}"`, a dynamic bean with a static value in suqare brackets made into a method by adding `()` as a postfix, you'll see another line of code above it

```
<h:outputText value="#{templatesBeanName[contentPropertyName]}"/>
```

What effectively is done here is to have a dynamic bean ***AND*** a dynamic property name being used.

So my conclusion is that with this example what they are trying to illustrate is that you are able to pass on a dynamic bean, and on that bean use either both static or dynamic methods and properties(static properties and dynamic methods not being in the example)

Comment: Passing a dynamic bean *and* a dynamic property-- it almost sounds lambda-like in passing behaviour through parameters.

Comment: @craigcaulfield: YES!, lets start programming in views again ;-)